# add where condition make MDX query slow (olap4j)

Tags: performance, mdx, mondrian, olap4j

I'm using **MONDRIAN** server and **OLAP4j** API in a Java Web application, i have a performance issues when adding a where close to my queries.
MDX query like :

```
SELECT 
   CrossJoin(
     {[Product.ProductHierarchie].[AllProduct]}
   , {[Measures].[Quantity]}
   ) ON COLUMNS,
   [Client.ClientHierarchie].[AllClient].Children ON ROWS
FROM [sales_data_cube]
```

0.3 second to be done. But when adding a where clause, like 
`WHERE ([Period].&[start_period]:[Period].&[end_period])`,

to get the sales between a start/end periods, the query take more than **250 seconds** with a small fact table (8500 rows).

What i should do to have a better performance?

The application is running on a tomcat server with memory limit = 8GB, Data base server : MySQL 5.6.17

Comment: Instead of `WHERE` clause try moving it to a subselect like so - `FROM 
   (
 SELECT {[Period].&[start_period]:[Period].&[end_period]} ON 0 
 FROM [sales_data_cube]
   )`

Comment: Mondrian cannot recognize the subselect clause, it does not support MDX subqueries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, the problem was in the configuration of Mondrian.
Mondrian use the logging package ([log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html)) where actually call 'Debug'-method every time they compared two objects when using a where condition.

The solution is to change the log4j-configuration and stopping the 'Debug'-mod. I have added this simple code to set up log4j, before the creation of OLAP Connection:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getRootLogger().removeAllAppenders();
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new NullAppender());
Class.forName("mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver");
Connection connolap = ...
```

[more details about this issue (Mondrian Slow MDX Query)](http://ericbouwers.blogspot.fr/2007/11/trivia-pentaho-mondrian-slow-mdx-query.html)

Comment: While I have no experience of working on olap4j, i really appreciate you coming back here and adding a well researched answer. It really adds value to the site when people do that.